# How to remove the query parameter from url of socket.io-client

Tags: vue.js, websocket, socket.io

I am using vuejs and Websockets in it so I installed this package https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client and follow its official documentation https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

```
export default {
    mounted(){
        this.socket()
    },
    methods: {
        socket(){
            const socket = io('https://demo.com/api',{
                path: '/somedata'
            });
        }   
    }
}
```

but I am getting this error in my console "GET https://demo.com/somedata/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MnY8GnG 404(NOT FOUND)"

How can I remove the other parameters from this url ( like EIO ) so I can get the proper data of API.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I am having this problem...thanks